# sam build - DockerException, "Install pypiwin32 package to enable npipe:// support"

Tags: docker, aws-api-gateway, aws-cli, aws-sam, aws-sam-cli

I'm trying to create the helloworld template through the AWS SAM CLI. `sam init` runs fine, and creates the usual file structure. Once I `cd` to the directory and run `sam build`, I get the following error:

```
Error: Install pypiwin32 package to enable npipe:// support
Traceback:
    ...
An unexpected error was encountered while executing "sam build".
```

I have installed Docker, and I've also tried running `pip install pypiwin32` in the same directory, but the error is still thrown. What's the cause of this issue? (If it's a Docker problem, I can try reinstalling it, but I've done that before and nothing changed.)

**Full error log below if needed:**

```
Starting Build use cache

Error: Install pypiwin32 package to enable npipe:// support
Traceback:
  File "D:\aws-cli\runtime\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1055, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "D:\aws-cli\runtime\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1657, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "D:\aws-cli\runtime\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1404, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "D:\aws-cli\runtime\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 760, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\aws-cli\runtime\lib\site-packages\click\decorators.py", line 84, in new_func
    return ctx.invoke(f, obj, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\aws-cli\runtime\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 760, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\aws-cli\runtime\lib\site-packages\samcli\lib\telemetry\metric.py", line 184, in wrapped
    raise exception  # pylint: disable=raising-bad-type
  File "D:\aws-cli\runtime\lib\site-packages\samcli\lib\telemetry\metric.py", line 149, in wrapped
    return_value = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\aws-cli\runtime\lib\site-packages\samcli\lib\utils\version_checker.py", line 42, in wrapped
    actual_result = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\aws-cli\runtime\lib\site-packages\samcli\cli\main.py", line 92, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\aws-cli\runtime\lib\site-packages\samcli\commands\build\command.py", line 180, in cli
    do_cli(
  File "D:\aws-cli\runtime\lib\site-packages\samcli\commands\build\command.py", line 276, in do_cli
    ctx.run()
  File "D:\aws-cli\runtime\lib\site-packages\samcli\commands\build\build_context.py", line 254, in run
    builder = ApplicationBuilder(
  File "D:\aws-cli\runtime\lib\site-packages\samcli\lib\build\app_builder.py", line 159, in __init__
    self._docker_client = docker_client if docker_client else docker.from_env()
  File "D:\aws-cli\runtime\lib\site-packages\docker\client.py", line 84, in from_env
    return cls(
  File "D:\aws-cli\runtime\lib\site-packages\docker\client.py", line 40, in __init__
    self.api = APIClient(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\aws-cli\runtime\lib\site-packages\docker\api\client.py", line 158, in __init__
    raise DockerException(

An unexpected error was encountered while executing "sam build".
Search for an existing issue:
https://github.com/aws/aws-sam-cli/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+Bug%3A%20sam%20build%20-%20DockerException
Or create a bug report:
https://github.com/aws/aws-sam-cli/issues/new?template=Bug_report.md&title=Bug%3A%20sam%20build%20-%20DockerException
```